# Reference for irreducible representations of direct product of compact lie groups.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products, exterior-algebra, direct-product

In some unpublished notes which are not publically available, a version of the following result is proved:

> If $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are complex, irreducible representations of compact Lie groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, then the exterior tensor product $\phi_1\boxtimes \phi_2$ is an irreducible representation of the direct product $G_1\times G_2$.

I am using this result in my thesis, but I don't want to write up a full proof because I would need some concepts that would need a proper explanation first, which would be out of the scope of my work.

I would like to have a published source to cite for this result, ideally a book. It looks like such a simple result that I am sure it must be proved in some representation theory book out there, but I haven't been able to find one.

Does anyone know of any book containing this (or a similar) statement?

Thank you

Comment: I would assume some version of this to appear in most comprehensive texts on representation theory. The main thing in the specific version here is the question of it still being a representation of Lie groups (but that too should be quite straight forward).

Comment: I looked in several books and couldn't find anywhere this was stated and proven. It is stated (but not proven) as Exercise 2.36 in Fulton and Harris.

Comment: I also assumed I would find it in any comprehensive text but I couldn't. I have also looked on all the textbooks I know of (Fulton and Harris, Hall, Simon, James an Liebeck, Varadarajan, Atiyah..) but couldn't find a proof. Either I'm very bad at looking into books, or for some reason people don't like to prove this.

Comment: What you will find in textbooks is the orthogonality of characters. Characters of irreps are of $L^2$ norm $1$ and that's an iff when considering finite dimensional reps. Then your result follows trivially by Fubini's Thm.